# ubuntu image for multiple computers

Tags: ubuntu, installation, reinstall, disk-image, multiple-instances

I need to set up several computers to be exactly the same:

- install ubuntu
- apt-get some software
- create specific users
- tweak those users' settings and defaults
- create some global environment variables for every user
- and then test, to make sure it all works.

This is very tedious, and I'm wondering how to speed it up.

Is there a way to create an image from a laptop that has all this setup, and then use that image for other computers?

The computers have different processors, different disk size, different memory.

Comment: Unlike Windows, Ubuntu handles hardware changes quite well. You can try creating an image of installed system with CloneZilla and replicate it on other computers.

Answer (score 2):

I would do all of the above on whatever system, then take a Clonezilla image of the partition, rather than the entire drive. Clonezilla has selectable options for this along the way. Clonezilla can then be used to lay this image down on other machines.

It's been a while since I've actually done this, but I think it's necessary to maintain the partition size when doing this - that is, if the partition you want to clone is whatever size when you take an image, that is is the size that the partition you wish to copy the image to needs to be in order to work. I remember having an issue with this at some point in time.

Just my experience so far...as always, your mileage may vary.

Comment: architecture would need to be maintained as well or match the lowest common denominator, i.e. you can't create a 64-bit base install, and get it working on 32-bit only systems . . .

Comment: apt-cache doesn't find clonezilla. Where do I get it?

Comment: @ernie: That is true. I neglected to mention that. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Marjeta: Clonezilla is not an application that you would install using apt. Clonezilla is a live distro available from clonezilla.org as an ISO image which you can burn to a disc or USB drive (using UNetbootin is how I do it) to boot your machine and take the image. I suggest Googling around some to familiarize yourself with the process of taking a drive imgage in this way.